# In OWL, how can I enforce a type correlation between the values of two different properties?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

## Introduction

I want to model some kind of software ecosystem with the help of an ontology. I am planning to use OWL (perhaps it's not the right choice?). The ecosystem consists of many small functions each of which performs a specific task which requires specific inputs and produces specific outputs. For example there might be the following functions:

- `ImageToText`: a function which takes an `Image` as input and produces a `Text` string with all the contained words as output.
- `TextToWordcount`: a function which takes a `Text` as input and produces a `Wordcount` integer – representing the number of words in the text – as output.

While `Text` is simply a string and `Wordcount` is simply a (non-negative) integer, I would model these as separate `Data` entities in order to capture their semantic meaning (or, perhaps, create dedicated data types).

Then I want to use the ontology to answer questions such as "if I have an `Image`, is there a way to combine the functions of my ecosystem in such a way that I get a `Wordcount` of the text that is contained in the image?". In the example above that would be chaining the functions `ImageToText --> TextToWordcount`.

Similarly, if someone else claims "I can chain the functions `ImageToText --> TextToWordcount` in order to produce a `Wordcount` from an `Image`", I want to be able to check whether that claim makes sense, i.e., whether the mentioned functions can really work together and produce the claimed output.

I thought about modeling this via dedicated `Input` and `Output` classes, one per `Function`. Then I can add restrictions for the specific subclasses. For example, `ImageToTextOutput` would have the restriction `hasOutputData exactly 1 Text`.

A sample ontology can be found below.

## The question

In the actual system the input types may not only be data, but also data wrapped in some container (e.g., instead of requiring a string as input, a function would require a JSON payload which contains the string under the key `"text"`). Suppose that `TextToWordcount` is such a function and it requires a `Container` as input which itself must contain the `Text`. In addition, there is a dedicated helper function `DataToContainer` which simply puts any kind of data inside a `Container`. That is, if the input to `DataToContainer` is an `Image` then the output is a `Container` which contains the `Image`. Similarly, if the input is a `Text` then the output is a `Container` which contains the `Text`.

The problem I have with that `DataToContainer` function is to model the correlation between its input and output. That is, the resulting container must contain an individual of the same type as was present in the input. Currently I have:

```
Class: DataToContainerInput
    SubClassOf:
        Input,
        hasInputData exactly 1 Data
    
    
Class: DataToContainerOutput
    SubClassOf:
        Output,
        hasOutputDataContainer exactly 1 (Container and (containsData exactly 1 Data))
```

However, the above definition expresses that *both* the input and output may refer to *any* `Data`. For example, the input could be a `Text` and the output could be a `Container` containing an `Image`. I'm looking for a way that let's me restrict the individual of `Data` in `DataToContainerOutput` to be of the same type as the one in `DataToContainerInput`. The input should remain general (i.e., accept `Data`) but the output must be of the same specific type.

In the end, I want to be able to answer similar questions as above. For example, "given an `Image`, is there a way to produce a `Wordcount`?". The answer would be yes, since `ImageToText --> DataToContainer --> TextToWordcount` is a working function chain. However, with my current definition it seems that this answer cannot be inferred since `DataToContainer` claims to produce a `Container` which contains any `Data` which is not what the next function `TextToWordcount` expects (it expects `Text` which is a subclass of `Data`).

---

## P.S.: Python equivalent

I come from software where I work a lot with Python. In Python I would model the relationship with type hints in the following way. I hope that it helps in explaining my reasoning.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Data:
    pass

class Image(Data):
    pass

class Text(Data):
    pass

D = TypeVar('D', bound=Data)

@dataclass
class Container(Generic[D]):
    data: D


def data_to_container(data: D) -> Container[D]:
    return Container(data)


reveal_type(data_to_container(Image()).data)  # Revealed type is "Image"
reveal_type(data_to_container(Text()).data)  # Revealed type is "Text"
```

## P.S.: Example ontology

In Manchester syntax (created with Protégé):

```
Prefix: : <http://example.org/functions/>
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>



Ontology: <http://example.org/functions>


ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#containsData>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Container>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Data>
    
    
ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#hasInput>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Function>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Input>
    
    
ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#hasInputData>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Input>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Data>
    
    
ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#hasInputDataContainer>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Input>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Container>
    
    
ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#hasOutput>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Function>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Output>
    
    
ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#hasOutputData>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Output>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Data>
    
    
ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#hasOutputDataContainer>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Output>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Container>
    
    
ObjectProperty: <http://example.org/functions#isFollowedBy>

    Domain: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Function>
    
    Range: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Function>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Container>

    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Data>

    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#DataToContainer>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Function>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasInput> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#DataToContainerInput>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasOutput> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#DataToContainerOutput>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#DataToContainerInput>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Input>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasInputData> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#Data>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#DataToContainerOutput>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Output>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasOutputDataContainer> exactly 1 (<http://example.org/functions#Container>
         and (<http://example.org/functions#containsData> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#Data>))
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Function>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#isFollowedBy> max 1 <http://example.org/functions#Function>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#GrayscaleImage>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Image>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Image>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Data>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#ImageToText>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Function>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasInput> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#ImageToTextInput>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasOutput> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#ImageToTextOutput>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#ImageToTextInput>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Input>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasInputData> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#Image>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#ImageToTextOutput>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Output>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasOutputData> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#Text>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Input>

    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Integer>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Data>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Output>

    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#String>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Data>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Text>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#String>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#TextToWordcount>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Function>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasInput> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#TextToWordcountInput>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasOutput> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#TextToWordcountOutput>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#TextToWordcountInput>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Input>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasInputDataContainer> exactly 1 (<http://example.org/functions#Container>
         and (<http://example.org/functions#containsData> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#String>))
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#TextToWordcountOutput>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Output>,
        <http://example.org/functions#hasOutputData> exactly 1 <http://example.org/functions#Wordcount>
    
    
Class: <http://example.org/functions#Wordcount>

    SubClassOf: 
        <http://example.org/functions#Integer>
```